# how to removed space around website and Navigation bar [CSS][margin collapsing]

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm currently struggling with something called margin collapsing.
I did get a workaround by using `position: relative` and `top:-20px` (you can see in the code under the banner and `main-nav` I commented it out) I was just wondering if there is a better way to fix this problem?

Also, my workaround solution creates a gap between my header and first paragraph and there is clearly still a visible padding around the whole website.
How could I fix this?

You can see a live version at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/VivAZ/pen/mLVLJb)

Is there also a way to make the nav bar sticky and expand animation like at my old WordPress website: [Wordpress website](http://www.severegaming.co.za) or do you need JavaScript for that?

html code:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contect ="ie=edge">
<title>Severe Gaming</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <!-- Navigation --> 
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul >
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header class="banner">
    </header>
    <!-- Top Container -->
    <section class="container">
       <header class="box paragraph1">
           <h1>Welcome to Severe Gaming</h1>
           <p>Severe Gaming is a Multi-Gaming Organisation founded in 2010. Over the years it has served as a platform for players to compete in many different games at a highly competitive level as well as serving as a home for players to improve their skills and build strong relationships with one another. Severe Gaming sees the potential in the South African eSports scene and aims to develop and grow with it as the future unfolds.</p>
       </header>
       <div class ="picture1">
       </div>
       <div class ="picture2">
       </div>
         <header class="box paragraph2">
           <h1>Welcome to Severe Gaming</h1>
           <p>Severe Gaming is a Multi-Gaming Organisation founded in 2010. Over the years it has served as a platform for players to compete in many different games at a highly competitive level as well as serving as a home for players to improve their skills and build strong relationships with one another. Severe Gaming sees the potential in the South African eSports scene and aims to develop and grow with it as the future unfolds.</p>
       </header>
    </section>
   <div class="footer">
   </div>
 </div> 
 <!-- Wrapper Ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
    /* CSS Variables */
:root {
    --primary: #FFFFFF;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: var(--primary);
}

body {
    background: #0b0e17;
  /*  margin: 30px 50px; */
    line-height: 1.4;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
}
.banner {
    /*position:relative;
    top:-40px;*/
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/earz6x/header.png);
    height:392px;
}

/* Navigation */
.main-nav ul{
    /* position:relative;
    top:-20px; */
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap:20px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    background: url("https://image.ibb.co/jd1ozH/Nav_bar.png");
    height:90px; 
}

.main-nav a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--primary);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'paragraph1 picture1'
        'picture2 paragraph2' ;
}

.paragraph1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    grid-area: paragraph1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;

}
.box {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.box h1{
  border-bottom: 3px solid; 
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
}

.picture1 {
    grid-area: picture1;
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ddNWKH/mockup.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;   
}

.picture2 {
    grid-area: picture2;
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ddNWKH/mockup.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;  
}

.paragraph2 {
    grid-area: paragraph2;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;    
}

.footer{
    background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/f5fqDc/footer.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML adds default margin to the page. To remove that, put this in your css file.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:flex` and `float:right` in ul

```css
/* CSS Variables */
:root {
    --primary: #FFFFFF;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: var(--primary);
}

body {
    background: #0b0e17;
  /*  margin: 30px 50px; */
    line-height: 1.4;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
}
.banner {
    /*position:relative;
    top:-40px;*/
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/earz6x/header.png);
    height:392px;
}

/* Navigation */
.main-nav ul{
    /* position:relative;
    top:-20px; */
    display: flex;
  float:right;
    grid-column-gap:20px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    background: url("https://image.ibb.co/jd1ozH/Nav_bar.png");
    height:90px; 
}

.main-nav a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--primary);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'paragraph1 picture1'
        'picture2 paragraph2' ;
}

.paragraph1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    grid-area: paragraph1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    
}
.box {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.box h1{
  border-bottom: 3px solid; 
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
}

.picture1 {
    grid-area: picture1;
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ddNWKH/mockup.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;   
}

.picture2 {
    grid-area: picture2;
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ddNWKH/mockup.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;  
}

.paragraph2 {
    grid-area: paragraph2;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;    
}

.footer{
    background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/f5fqDc/footer.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contect ="ie=edge">
<title>Severe Gaming</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <!-- Navigation --> 
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul >
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header class="banner">
    </header>
    <!-- Top Container -->
    <section class="container">
       <header class="box paragraph1">
           <h1>Welcome to Severe Gaming</h1>
           <p>Severe Gaming is a Multi-Gaming Organisation founded in 2010. Over the years it has served as a platform for players to compete in many different games at a highly competitive level as well as serving as a home for players to improve their skills and build strong relationships with one another. Severe Gaming sees the potential in the South African eSports scene and aims to develop and grow with it as the future unfolds.</p>
       </header>
       <div class ="picture1">
       </div>
       <div class ="picture2">
       </div>
         <header class="box paragraph2">
           <h1>Welcome to Severe Gaming</h1>
           <p>Severe Gaming is a Multi-Gaming Organisation founded in 2010. Over the years it has served as a platform for players to compete in many different games at a highly competitive level as well as serving as a home for players to improve their skills and build strong relationships with one another. Severe Gaming sees the potential in the South African eSports scene and aims to develop and grow with it as the future unfolds.</p>
       </header>
    </section>
   <div class="footer">
   </div>
 </div> 
 <!-- Wrapper Ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but i think i'm gonna keep it as it is now! Although just want to let you know that for some reason the nav bar shrinks down with that so i think u might need to add backgroud-width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

To stop the nav from moving when you scroll you'll want to add position: fixed, width: 100%. Make sure to add a margin-top to your banner after so it isn't covered by your nav.

```
.banner {
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/earz6x/header.png);
    height:392px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

/* Navigation */
.main-nav ul{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap:20px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    background: url("https://image.ibb.co/jd1ozH/Nav_bar.png");
    height:90px; 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm not sure about the animation. Currently, there doesn't seem to be one on your page. But yes, js is needed for that. Here is a site to help you with that: https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

On your site, the banner is in the center of page, with black background. If you want that, your css should be:

```
.banner {
    /*position:relative;
    top:-40px;*/
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/earz6x/header.png);
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    height:392px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
```